# From within Steam, how can I automatically disable the HUD hotkey upon a game's launch, and reenable it upon that game closing?

Tags: shortcut-keys, steam, hud

I've looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142861/can-i-disable-dash-and-hud-hotkeys-when-fullscreen-in-dosbox) but there's nothing automatic about it, I'm not trying to open a GUI and fiddle with settings everytime I start and stop playing a game.

In Steam, it's possible to edit the launch options of a game. For instance I use bumblebee to enable my laptop's nvidia card by adding `primusrun %command%` to the launch options. Here we should be able to call starting and ending scripts (or just string together some commands) to disable HUD hotkey buttons during gameplay and re-enable them afterward. Something along the lines of `launchscript ; %command% ; endscript` perhaps.

This means we need a command line way to enable and disable the HUD hotkey. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/337210/25082) shows a CLI method. I've tried this and it works from the terminal but not when I try to call it via the launch options within Steam. When trying it with `bash -c` I run into issues with the delimiters but that is solved using gsettings instead.

I've tried all of the following but with no success:

`dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '[""]' ; primusrun %command%`

`bash -c 'dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '[""]'' ; primusrun %command%`

`bash -c 'dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '[""]' ; primusrun %command%'`

`bash -c "dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '[""]' ; primusrun %command%"`

I've also tried using gsettings rather than dconf. 
e.g. `bash -c 'gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud '[""]'' ; primusrun %command%` but again it works in the terminal but not from the launch options.

I'm pretty sure I'm just running into syntax problems, how can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Make a script *nohudrun* like the *primusrun* is done:

```
#!/bin/sh

old_key="$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib dconf read /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud)"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud "['']" 
"$@"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud "$old_key"
```

And invoke it like that:

```
nohudrun primusrun %command%
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib is for breaking from x32 environment of Steam, because dconf can't find x64 libs (maybe there is a better way). That is the cause why it fails from 'launch options', I think.

You can also add some locking to be able to correctly restore the keybinding when multiple games are run through that script.

**P. S.** How to know what's wrong? Just print stderr to file:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud "['']" 2>>/home/velkan/errr
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. The game just never starts. Is there a particular directory I should be putting the script in?

Comment: Better specify the full path like `/home/velkan/nohudrun primusrun %command%` (or put the script in some directory that in the $PATH variable; but that is not recommended), and don't forget to make it executable

Comment: I didi try that, but I'll try again. I tried both using the full path and also adding the directory to the $PATH variable (think I failed in that though)