# Ubuntu freezes when running steam game counter strike and hitting the Windows key

Tags: unity, games, unity-dash, steam, hud

I recently updated Ubuntu to 15.10, and since whenever I am playing counter strike on steam and hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, volume up, volume down, mute or any key-bored button that will show a UI over the counter strike game window Ubuntu freezes!

The only thing I can access is the terminal using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>**.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Do you face this problem with counter strike only?

Comment: @MarcosRocha 64bit

Comment: @Sneetsher I don't know, I don't have any other game to try.

Comment: @Waqleh, I have urban terror, it is really outstanding issue for Unity & GnomeShell. After seeing your post, I wrote new question here http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87184/problematic-with-desktop-hud-activation-using-hot-key-or-hot-corner in user experience site. They may give me a better approach to fix this. then I will push for that in a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same problem sometime ago with all full-screen app using `wine`. There multiple ways the may lead to same result:

- Changing keyboard may help. I'm using two laptops in one of the I always hit the Alt key.
- Disable hot keys temporary as mentioned here:

  [Can I disable Dash and HUD hotkeys when fullscreen (in DOSBox)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/142861/26246)

  or [From within Steam, how can I automatically disable the HUD hotkey upon a game's launch, and re-enable it upon that game closing?](https://askubuntu.com/q/610265/26246)
- Used different Window Manager while using those app & games. `openbox` is very light one which does not have any fancy to distract you.

  1. Install it

     ```
     sudo apt-get install openbox
     ```
  2. Launch it

     ```
     sudo su
     startx openbox
     ```
  3. Switching between Unity & Openbox, by default:

     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> Unity

     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> Openbox

     but it could be different depending on you setup, you may try from <kbd>F1</kbd> and up.

Comment: I am **not** running the game on **wine** . Also I want to know what is the problem to fix it, not to go around it.

Comment: @Waqleh, I agree, these are just work around. If you search here or in launchpad bugs, you are going to find many threads about this bug in Unity HUD.